# Why does the Facebook backend return 0 as the user id when authenticating from within a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, plugins, oauth

thanks for reading! Here's what I'm up to.

I'm writing a WordPress plugin that makes use of the PHP SDK (latest version 3.1.1) that Facebook [provides](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk). My application is registered with Facebook as a website because it infact acts like a website, even though it's embedded in WordPress.

This SDK comes with an example.php that is very straightforward and easy to understand. If I put this file on my server, it just works. I made sure that the certificate file and the SDK files are in the right place and accessible by the script.

However, if I do the exact same thing from within a WordPress plugin (from the admin page of the plugin), the Facebook backend won't return the user id but will always return 0 instead. The problem with FB returning 0 is pretty common, but the reasons for it seem to vary a lot.

I have to mention that this behavior wasn't always like this. It began just a few weeks ago. I'm suspecting that the FB backend somehow checks for indirect API calls and that calling it from within a WordPress plugin seems to violate FBs auth rules in some way (CSRF issue?). But I'm not sure.

Has anybody got a clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my guess:

Facebook will not be able to access the backend of your WordPress blog since it requires authentication. So the example.php code will not be visible to it from a WordPress admin panel.

When served raw on your server, there are no such access controls and Facebook is able to reach the page.

If this is the case, my suggestion would be to turn this into a non-admin plugin, perhaps by adding a rewrite rule using the [WP_Rewrite class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite).

Comment: Thanks for you immediate answer! What makes me wonder is, if this is the case, then why would it have worked two weeks ago? Does FB really need access to the WP backend when called from within a PHP script that is part of a WP plugin? Could you explain this technically for me? I wish I could work around this like you said, but I can't turn this into a non-admin plugin, because that's the point of the plugin, it's for the blog owner.

Comment: When you log in w/a username and pass, WordPress drops some cookies (http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies) so it recognizes you as a logged in user. If WordPress simply allowed any bot to access your backend anyone could change or destroy your install. Facebook is not authenticated and as such has no cookies when it requests your admin page, so WP throws an error. When you served example.php raw, WordPress was not involved at all -- Facebook talked to your server directly.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It seems more plausible to me now that FB needs to request the admin page as part of the authentication process. I am still wondering why it initially worked. It should have always produced the error - but didn't.

I will try to solve it with URL rewriting.

Thanks!

Comment: Another odd thing just happened. I was adding the parameter 'redirect_uri' to the configuration array with which I initialize my Facebook instance and - strangely - the authentication again works flawlessly - from within the WordPress plugin's admin page.